# Rerunning my program in Java

Tags: java

I am trying to make it so that if the username and / or password aren't correct, the program will run it over again, instead of just doing the print command in the else statement. I tried putting another while loop in the else statement and nesting the if statement inside that checks the username and password inside of it, but then I realized I would have to copy all the code from the if statement into the else statement, which obviously seems like it is not the correct solution and is probably very clunky. What is the right way to refer the program back to run from the start or something?

```
    // Declare Variables
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String username;
    String password;
    String calculator = "calculator";
    String renameUser = "renameUser";
    String renamePass = "renamePass";
    String getIp = "getIp";
    String exit = "exit";
    String command;

        // Prompt User to login

        System.out.println("Username: ");
        username = input.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Password: ");
        password = input.nextLine();

            if (username.equals("admin") && password.equals("admin") ) // Must use the equals method of string class to compare, == operator will NOT work.
            {
                System.out.println("Success! Welcome " + username + "!");
                while (true) // Infinite loop using the true statement
                {   command = input.nextLine(); 
                    if (command.equals(calculator)) 
                    {   // calculator code here
                        if (command.equals(renameUser)) 
                        {   // renameUser code here
                            if (command.equals(renamePass)) 
                            {   // renamePass code here                             
                                if (command.equals(getIp)) 
                                {   // getIp code here
                                    if(command.equals(exit)) 
                                    { 
                                    break;
                                    }
                                    System.out.println("Logging out!");
                                }       
                            }           
                        }       
                    }                       
                }   
            } 
            else 
            {   
                System.out.println("Wrong username or password, please try again."); 
            }
}
```

}

Comment: Do an if/else instead of nested ifs. It's wrong logic. Also, use equalsIgnoreCase() for non-case-sensitive

Comment: @AndrewL I don't understand, I am using nested ifs because each if has a specific function if triggered

Comment: Nested ifs check if ALL conditions are true..

Comment: @AndrewL oooooh woooops, LOL. Thanks for bringing that up, yeah wow. That is totally wrong, Thanks! :D

Answer (score 1):

Think about the below logic

```
if (command.equals(calculator)) 
{   // calculator code here
     if (command.equals(renameUser)) 
     {
```

If `command` equals `calculator` then how can it equal `renameUser`

You should have it

```
if (....) {
}
else if (...) {
}
```

statement or as a switch statement

Answer (score 0):

This snippet here is increasing the [cyclomatic complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclomatic_complexity) of your software  making it hard to make a decision, if you want to change that later, you have more chances to break the code than success

```
   if (command.equals(calculator)) 
                    {   // calculator code here
                        if (command.equals(renameUser)) 
                        {   // renameUser code here
                            if (command.equals(renamePass)) 
                            {   // renamePass code here                             
                                if (command.equals(getIp)) 
                                {   // getIp code here
                                    if(command.equals(exit)) 
                                    {
```

try to design something more like a witch case logic

## Example:

```
switch (userInput) {
    case renameUser:
        renameUser();
        break;
    case getIp:
        getIp();
        break;
    ...

    default:
        break;
    }
```

Comment: Try adding equalsIgnoreCase for better flexibility

Comment: Thank you very much, yeah I've just realized I have coded this not the way I intended too. :)

Comment: @AndrewL Will do :)